# NullPointerException in IabHelper.queryPurchases

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

Today I discovered an application crash report for my Android app involving the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.Bundle com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.getPurchases(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.myapp.utils.IabHelper.queryPurchases(IabHelper.java:878)
at com.myapp.utils.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:572)
at com.myapp.utils.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:545)
at com.myapp.utils.IabHelper$2.run(IabHelper.java:645)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

(line numbers are changed from the original -or what [looks like to be the original](https://code.google.com/r/studiozanandroid-appbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java?r=7ec85a9b619fc5f85023bc8125e7e6b1ab4dd69f), because of custom reformatting)

Normally, one would modify his own code to check for unassigned class members. The problem is that this code is copied&pasted right from Android SDK, because `IabHelper` is a class that Android SDK [provides](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample) as a good starting point for implementing In-app Billing v3

The guilty line is the second

```
logDebug("Calling getPurchases with continuation token: " + continueToken);
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(), itemType, continueToken);
```

It seems that the service is not connected at the time the method is invoked. This error occurred on a Nexus 5 device (as per Developer Console)

- Is this a known problem with Android 5?
- Is there an up-to-date version of the IAB Helper?
- What can I do rather than manually editing the code to handle NPE someway?

Comment: IabHelper is now obsolete and should no longer be used.  
Google released a BillingClient library: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html

Comment: The question is in fact very old

Comment: This question is still ranked very high on Google. I stumbled across the error myself and discovered they released the new library a few weeks ago. This is just a note for all the other devs coming by.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I modified this code ...

```
    do {
        logDebug("Calling getPurchases with continuation token: " + continueToken);
        Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(), itemType, continueToken);
        // ...
    }
```

To be this ...

```
    do {
        logDebug("Calling getPurchases with continuation token: " + continueToken);
        if (mService == null || mContext == null) {
            logError("Our service and/or our context are null.  Exiting.");
            return IABHELPER_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
        }
        Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(), itemType, continueToken);
        // ...
    }
```

This is almost certainly because the process is being run asynchronously and the activity/app has (or is being) closed when the result returns.

Comment: Reasonable: when the Activity is paused, I don't know what happens to the Looper. Anyway the Spring context is the owner of my IabHelper instance, so it's kinda difficult that it magically becomes null. --Mistery

Comment: Just found out that this happens in this scenario: open your app. Minimize it and open the PlayStore. Cick on the device button that shows all open tasks. Swipe away/kill the PlayStore task. Click on your app when in the screen that shows all open tasks. You solution prevents this NullException so thanks a lot.